# Probability that a certain sequence is belonging to a certain transition matrix

Tags: probability, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I have the following transition matrices, one for `Maria` and one for `Anna`:

```
import pandas as pd
anna_dt = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['tomato', 'carrots', 'cheese'],
                              'tomato': [0.1, 0.4, 0.1],
                              'carrots': [0.5,0.5,0.1],
                               'cheese': [0.4,0.1,0.8]})
maria_dt = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['tomato', 'carrots', 'cheese'],
                              'tomato': [0.7, 0.4, 0.8],
                              'carrots': [0.15,0.3,0.1],
                               'cheese': [0.15,0.3,0.1]})

anna_dt
source  tomato  carrots cheese
0   tomato  0.1 0.5 0.4
1   carrots 0.4 0.5 0.1
2   cheese  0.1 0.1 0.8

maria_dt
source  tomato  carrots cheese
0   tomato  0.7 0.15    0.15
1   carrots 0.4 0.30    0.30
2   cheese  0.8 0.10    0.10
```

What these matrices tell me, is that e.g., there is an `80%` chance that `Anna` is eating `cheese` after eating `cheese` and `40%` that `Anna` is eating `tomato` after eating `carrots`

Similarly for `Maria` we have that she has `70%` chance that she is `tomato` after eating `tomato` and `80%` chance that she is `tomato` after eating `cheese`.

My question is:

- Given a sequence of foods: `carrots -> carrots -> tomato -> carrots -> tomato -> cheese -> cheese -> cheese`, how can I calculate the probability of this sequence belonging to `Anna` and the probability of this sequence belonging to `Maria` ? (this sequence is most like belonging to `Maria` since we can see a lot of `carrots` followed by `carrots` and a lot of `cheese` followed by `cheese`)

**EDIT**
The probability the first food is `tomato`, `carrots`, `cheese` is `[1/3, 1/3, 1/3]`

Comment: Which is the probability that the first eaten food is carrots, cheese or tomato?

Comment: @nicola you are right, forgot to specify that. It is 1/3, 1/3, 1/3. I will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

You first need to find sequence probability given the person. Then, through Bayes Theorem, you can find person probability given the sequence.

Since you are talking about a Markov chain, it has to be memoryless. Banking on this, let's say that you are looking for $S=ijkjk$ sequence:

$$
P(i-j-k-j-k)=P(i)*P(j|i)*P(k|j)*P(j|k)*P(k|j).
$$

Let's call $P(S)=P(j|i)*P(k|j)*P(j|k)*P(k|j)$.

You need to find $P(i)=\pi(i)$ through stationary probabilities, i.e.,

$$
\pi=M\pi.
$$

[Here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_2_3_probability_distributions.php) might help you with the stationary probabilities.

Note that I answered for a long period. If your period is short, the stationary probabilities are not yet obtained, which complicates things. Then, you need to find probability distribution at the $q^{th}$ step through $M^q$ and the best way is eigendecomposition. Let's say $M$ is your transition matrix. It can be expressed as $QDQ^{-1}$, where $D$ is the diagonal eigenvalue matrix. Then $M^q$ becomes:

$$
M^q=QD^qQ^{-1}
$$

Now, the probability that you get this sequence for the first time starting at $n^{th}$ step becomes

$$
P^n=\left(\prod_{q=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\left[M^{q-1} P_0\right]_i *P(S) \right)\right)*[M^{n}P_0]_i*P(S)
$$

The product in the parentheses is to make sure that the sequence you are looking for never happens before $n$, and $\left[M^{q-1} P_0\right]_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row of $M^{q-1} P_0$ column matrix, i.e., the probability of $i$ at the $(q-1)^{th}$ step.

If you are looking for the probability that it will happen within the first $m$ steps, just sum $P^n$.

So far, I calculated $P(S|M)$. This $M$ might belong to Anna or Maria. We just need to use the Bayes Theorem for the rest.

$$P(M_A|S)=\frac{P(S|M_A)P(A)}{P(S)},$$

and $P(S)=P(S|M_A)P(A)+P(S|M_M)P(M)$, where $P(A)$ and $P(M)$ are the probability of Anna or Maria eating something.